# QueryCursorImpl.getAll possibly loses data. Should I prefer IgniteCacheProxy.getAll?

Tags: ignite

I am trying to figure out what kind of `getAll` I should use. Currently, in a project, I work for, is implemented way through `QueryCursorImpl`

```
try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<IgnitePrimaryKey, V>> query = cache.query(new ScanQuery<>(filter))) {
    return query.getAll()
                .stream()
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
}
```

However, Most of the times my application cannot obtain data (data is empty). On the other hand `cache` variable is a `IgniteCacheProxy` and it has `getAll` method itself. There is some problem with set of keys, because actual signature of `IgniteCacheProxy.getAll` is following:

```
public Map<K, V> getAll(Set<? extends K> keys)
```

However, if I solve issue with keys, maybe I should prefer `IgniteCacheProxy.getAll` because I can see asynchronouse code inside it rather than `QueryCursorImpl.getAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to simply iterate over all the data you have in cache. If that's the case, then the easiest way would be to simple get `Iterator` (`IgniteCache` implements `Iterable`) and the loop through it. Using `getAll` would mean fetching all the data from a distributed cache to a client, which is typically a very bad idea, especially for large data set. Ignite iterator, however, will fetch data in pages and therefore will never blow the client's memory.

Comment: How do you control the size of the page when using IgniteCache as an iterator ?

Comment: Page size in this case is always 1024 (default value). If you need more flexibility, use query API.